# Long Term Capital Gains - NRI living in Australia. Should I or should I not pay in AUD or USD or INR

Tags: non-resident

Happy New Year to everyone

I am in a confusing state. Also reaching out to a few Tax Advisors. Not sure if someone in the forum has experienced this. I am an NRI (Indian) living in Australia on Work visa for past 1 year. I am planning to sell off my US Startup share at around considerable 6figures USD. Thinking - Should I pay LTCG in US or should I get paid in INR or in AUD ?

Anyone been in such a situation ?

Comment: Congrats!   Also, how LONG do you plan to live in Aus?  Just another year or so, or, forever?

Comment: Thanks. Want to stay forever. But depends on AUS PR etc :)

Answer (score 1):

As you are resident of AU, your ta liability will be in AU. You can claim credit for any LTCG paid / deducted in the US. There is no point involving INR in the transaction.
This response is on an assumption that the respective currencies are mentioned as the bank account in such currency is maintained at respective countries and that your query is regarding optimizing the tax incidence.